# Help creating a SCORING model/formula.......am I on the right track?

Tags: predictive-modeling, data-science-model, excel, scoring

Trying to create a basic machine scoring model, that takes in 4 parameters:

1. Number of maintenance events
2. Years of life left
3. Manufacturer support (bit - either yes or no)
4. Visual condition

The weightings of the parameters are also undecided. However, we know [Years of life remaining] will be much higher than the others. [Maintenance events] will be next highest, followed by [Visual Condition], and then [MFG Support].

We have an idea of where a given machine *should* fall in terms of the score and what year to replace it. But the formulas I create never really reflect that, so the weightings and formula probably have to change in unknown ways.

Additionally, the [Maintenance events] weighting will probably follow an s curve. A few maintenances isn't a big deal but as they accumulate, the maintenance score should drop faster and faster. But after some point where there has just been a ton of maintenance, it's score is already preetty bad and additional events wont drop the score much more. So it follows an S curve.

In terms of % for weighting, we were thinking about 60% for [Years of life left], 35% for [Maintenance], and 5% for [Condition]. Then maybe alter those around to create a weighting for [Support status]. So we have it set to add up to 100% total.

I am not sharing my formula because it is a bit random. Essentially, its just calculating the score for each based on the weighting (ex: for [Remaining Years of life], the max score it can get is 60.......if it's halfway through its life, it gets a score of 30). For [Maintenance], it is essentially calculated the same but with a s curve formula spat out by Excel.

I'm really struggling to determine the correct weightings and how to create the formula. Is there a standard way to handle questions like this?